In an infinite dimensional vector space, is it true that ''a linear transformation is isomorphism if and only if it sends basis to basis.''?
In a finite dimensional vector space, a linear transformation is an isomorphism if and only if it sends basis to basis. I wonder whether this result will also hold for infinite dimensional vector spaces or not?
Thanks for your help!

Yes, but we need the axiom of choice to ensure that bases continue to exist. In the absence of the axiom of choice there can be vector spaces without any basis at all, for example $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Ohh, that's interesting. Maybe I need to study the proof. Thanks for your comments.
